# How do you continue writing nested code after rendering a partial in slim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
= render 'header_splash'
  #about.section
    h2 You've reached our home page.
```

... where `header_splash.slim` looks like this:

```
#header_splash
  h1 Here's the splash image and the nav elements
```

I want the `#about` section to be rendered inside the `header_splash` `div` but it's rendering outside of it, even though it's nested in the code.

Is it at all possible to nest like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. If you want something rendered in a partial, you need to render it in the partial. You can pass in additional variables if necessary:

```
= render partial: 'header_splash', locals: { header_text: "you've reached ..." }
```

The `locals` hash will be available in your partial as variables:

```
h2= header_text
```